# What custom projection should I write to JOSM to get a flat projection

Tags: coordinate-system, josm

I am trying to write an osm file with JOSM for a flat surface (so, not mapping OSM data or data from the earth). This is for my own map that is a flat world.

Now, I managed to get the projection in JOSM to *look* about right by setting the custom projection to the following value:
`+proj=lonlat +wmssrs=epsg:5806`

It displays the world as a rectangle where I can draw lines. Now, if I draw a line that is 300km long and move it north and south its length changes. Near the equator, it is 300km. But all the way north it is near 10km or similar. How can I "fool" JOSM so that the line length is the same all over the map? As it should be on a flat surface.

This also affects the PicLayer. If I move the image north, it stretches wider. Near the equator the picture is fine.

I'm really new with all of this projection (or *coordinate reference systems*?) stuff so it could be just something like setting some factor in the projection right.

Comment: Since the Earth is not flat, we cannot define a geographical projection in which distances are conserved in all directions. I don't know if JOSM allows to assign a spatial reference system other than a geographical projection.

Comment: It sounds like it's trying to help you by reporting some sort of the geodesic distance versus the planar distance.